# Django model: Generate series number for each identifier upon saving the model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Good day!

I am very new in Django python web development.
I have a scenario where I need to automatically generate a property number and a set of `series number` per `location_code` as part of a property tag.

The format is `0000-00-00-0001-000000000`, the format definition is `'year' - 'gl_account' - 'sub_account' - 'series_number' - 'location_code'`

Example:

**for location code: 000000001 - office**

2021-10-10-0001-000000001 - table

2021-10-10-0002-000000001 - chair

2021-10-10-0003-000000001 - computer set

**for location code: 000000002 - warehouse office**

2021-10-10-0001-000000002 - table

2021-10-10-0002-000000002 - long table

2021-10-10-0003-000000002 - coffee maker

and so forth

I can already save the model with some part of the property number except the `series_number`. I see that you can generate random numbers or string, but it is not what I need. below is what I have, so far.

```
class Item(models.Model):

item                    = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
description             = models.TextField(max_length=200, null=True)
date_acquired           = models.DateField(max_length=10, null=True)
old_property_number     = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
property_number         = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
unit_of_measure         = models.ForeignKey('Uom', related_name='uom_item', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
unit_value              = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, null=True)
quantity_per_card           = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default='1')
quantity_per_physical_count = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, default='1' )
location                    = models.ForeignKey('Location', related_name='location_item', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
condition                   = models.ForeignKey('Condition', related_name='condition_item', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
acountable_person           = models.ForeignKey('Personnel', related_name='personnel_item', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
remarks                     = models.ForeignKey('Remarks', related_name='remarks_item', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
sub_major_group_and_gl_account    = models.ForeignKey('Account', related_name='sub_major_group_and_gl_account_item', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)


class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Item'

def __str__(self):
    return '%s - %s - %s' % (self.property_number, self.item, self.description)

# This is where I override the save function to save the format in the 'property_number' field #
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.property_number = '{}-{}-{}-{}'.format(self.date_acquired.year, self.sub_major_group_and_gl_account.sub_major_group_and_gl_account, 'series_number', self.location.location_code)
    super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Admin Site:
[image]

Comment: Can you share your model(s)?

Comment: @Iain Shelvington, I add it in the post. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67174385/2380028

As a reference, this is the answer I posted:

> I am answering my own question.
>
> I managed to solved my issues with the below `save` function. if anyone can improve my solution, it will be appreciated.
>
> Note: This is only applicable to newly added instance via admin site and **WILL NOT WORK** if the instance are imported via django-import-export. So, that would be the remaining issue for me, to automatically assigned the `data_counter` for every instance when using the import function in admin site.
>
> Else, will do the assignment manually in the excel file. XD

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    data_counter = Item.objects.filter(location=self.location).aggregate(counter=Count('id'))['counter'] # Count existing instance with matching "location id" of the new instance
    if self.pk is None and self.property_number is None: # if new instance and property number field is blank
        if data_counter is None: # if data_counter is empty/none, no matching instance
            data_counter = 1  # start at 1
        else: # else, if there is matching instance
            data_counter += 1 # add 1 to the data_counter
    elif self.pk is not None and self.property_number is None: # if not new instance and property number field is blank, Update an instance without property number
        if data_counter is None: # if data_counter is empty/none, the existing instance has no matching location id, Update
            data_counter = 1 # Existing instance start at 1
        else: # else, if there is matching instance
            data_counter += 1 # add 1 to the data_counter

    # data_counter will be the series number for every location ID
    self.property_number = '{}-{}-{:04d}-{}'.format(self.date_acquired.year, self.sub_major_group_and_gl_account.sub_major_group_and_gl_account, data_counter, self.location.location_code)
    
    super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```